# DJANGO ADDING NULL ON SAVE - IntegrityError at /****/ (1048, "***' cannot be null")

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I am trying to save a record of an entity call 'Persona' using Django's save function but when I try to insert the new object I get a 1048 IntegrityError because for any reason Django is adding NULL on a field that can not be null and is foreign key (the field is GeneroID that is a foreign key of the table Genero), this during the insert statement even when I am passing the value correctly. 
The odd thing is that I have values on the 'Genero' table and I am capturing correctly the value passed on the POST even if I print the value I get the value passed but for any strange reason DJango is adding Null on GeneroID field.

I am using MySQL with InnoDB and Django 1.8. And my model is generated from a legacy DB.

MODEL GENERO

```
class Genero(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
genero = models.CharField(db_column='Genero', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Genero'
```

MODEL PERSONA

```
class Persona(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
nombre = models.CharField(db_column='Nombre', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
apellido1 = models.CharField(db_column='Apellido1', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
apellido2 = models.CharField(db_column='Apellido2', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
numeroidentificacion = models.CharField(db_column='NumeroIdentificacion', unique=True, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
observaciones = models.CharField(db_column='Observaciones', max_length=255)  # Field name made lowercase.
fechanacimiento = models.DateField(db_column='FechaNacimiento')  # Field name made lowercase.
direccionfoto = models.CharField(db_column='DireccionFoto', max_length=500)  # Field name made lowercase.
genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, db_column='GeneroID',null=False)  # Field name made lowercase.
pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais, db_column='PaisID')  # Field name made lowercase.
lugarnacimiento = models.CharField(db_column='LugarNacimiento', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
direccion = models.ForeignKey(Direccion, db_column='DireccionID')  # Field name made lowercase.
profesion = models.CharField(db_column='Profesion', max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
puesto = models.CharField(db_column='Puesto', max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
lugartrabajo = models.CharField(db_column='LugarTrabajo', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'Persona'
```

VIEW.PY

```
def guardarpersona(request):
direccion = json.loads(request.POST['direccion[]'])
persona = json.loads(request.POST['persona[]'])
temp = Direccion()
temp.descripcion = direccion[1]['value']
temp.distrito = Distrito.objects.get(pk=direccion[0]['value'])
temp.save()

p = Persona()
p.nombre = persona[1]['value']
p.apellido1 = persona[2]['value']
p.apellido2 = persona[3]['value']
numeroidentificacion = persona[4]['value']
observaciones = persona[12]['value']
fechanacimiento = persona[6]['value']
direccionfoto = ''
genero = Genero.objects.get(pk=persona[5]['value'])
print(genero)
pais = Pais.objects.filter(id=persona[8]['value'])
print(pais)
lugarnacimiento = persona[7]['value']
direccion = temp
profesion = persona[9]['value']
puesto = persona[10]['value']
lugartrabajo = persona[11]['value'] 

try:
    p.save()
except Exception:
    from django.db import connection
    print (connection.queries[-1])
return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

DJANGO SQL STATEMENT BEEN GENERATED:

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 28, 2015 - 17:26:12
Django version 1.8.2, using settings 'WhiteKoala.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

Genero object

Pais: Pais object

{'sql': "INSERT INTO `Persona` (`Nombre`, `Apellido1`, `Apellido2`, `NumeroIdentificacion`, `Observaciones`, `FechaNacimiento`, `DireccionFoto`, `GeneroID`, `PaisID`, `LugarNacimiento`, `DireccionID`, `Profesion`, `Puesto`, `LugarTrabajo`) VALUES ('ANDREW', 'FONSECA', 'RIVAS', '', '', NULL, '', NULL, NULL, '', NULL, '', '', '')", 'time': '0.000'}
[28/Jun/2015 17:26:13]"POST /guardarpersona/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8

ERROR:

IntegrityError at /guardarpersona/
(1048, "Column 'GeneroID' cannot be null")

Also, here is a folder with some pics about my models, view.py, SQL statement been generated and the error:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wr3ve7cn9b0ofpm/AAD-57RXZGkxld74eCPhakERa?dl=0

Any idea about what I am doing wrong? I am new on Django and I would appreciate help and recommendations.

Comment: Can you post a bit more of your stack trace?

Comment: Sure! I added a couple more lines!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

I reread your question, and I think I see what's going wrong. You stopped setting the attributes:

```
p = Persona()
p.nombre = persona[1]['value']
p.apellido1 = persona[2]['value']
p.apellido2 = persona[3]['value']
```

For some reason, you stop setting attributes here:

```
numeroidentificacion = persona[4]['value']
observaciones = persona[12]['value']
fechanacimiento = persona[6]['value']
direccionfoto = ''
genero = Genero.objects.get(pk=persona[5]['value'])
print(genero)
pais = Pais.objects.get(id=persona[8]['value'])  # must `get` instead of `filter`
print(pais)
lugarnacimiento = persona[7]['value']
direccion = temp
profesion = persona[9]['value']
puesto = persona[10]['value']
lugartrabajo = persona[11]['value']
```

Change these to be attributes on your `Persona` before saving:

```
p.numeroidentificacion = persona[4]['value']
p.observaciones = persona[12]['value']
p.fechanacimiento = persona[6]['value']
p.direccionfoto = ''
p.genero = Genero.objects.get(pk=persona[5]['value'])
p.pais = Pais.objects.get(id=persona[8]['value'])
p.lugarnacimiento = persona[7]['value']
p.direccion = temp
p.profesion = persona[9]['value']
p.puesto = persona[10]['value']
p.lugartrabajo = persona[11]['value']
```

After that, try to save it:

```
 p.save()
```

If your objects are not None, then it should save.

---

**ORIGINAL:**

It looks like your ForeignKey is a non-nullable ForeignKey:

```
genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, db_column='GeneroID',null=False)
```

If you change this to:

```
genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, db_column='GeneroID',null=True)
```

Then it is nullable.

However, the IntegrityError makes it seem that the error is at the database level, so fixing this in the model definition won't completely fix the problem. The `IntegrityError` reveals that the **database** is actually throwing the error, so you'll have to look at your table definition and constraints.

Did you use Django with or without South to setup your tables (`syncdb` or `migrate`)? If so, then you have to run migrations after making this edit.

If not, then you will need to issue the proper sequel statements necessary to make that column Nullable in the database.

**WARNING 1: DO NOT SIMPLY RUN THE FOLLOWING WITHOUT TESTING**

**WARNING 2: If your application is relying on migrations (South or natively in Django), use that instead of the following!**

If your app does not rely on South or Django migrations, and you have (or someone has in the past), manually curated the tables, then you will need to issue SQL statements to amend the table to accept a NULL-able value here.

The SQL to do this *usually* looks *something* like the following:

```
ALTER TABLE `db_name`.`appname_persona`
MODIFY COLUMN `GeneroID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Moreover, it looks like you are passing `NULL` values in for a number of fields up there and nothing in the model definition is NULLABLE, so you will have to repeat this exercise for *each field you expect to regularly be empty* or you can make your `CharField`s defined to include `blank=True` and pass in empty strings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @erewok actually it was the problem. I can believe I did not see that before!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, db_column='GeneroID',null=False)
```

to

```
genero = models.ForeignKey(Genero, db_column='GeneroID',null=True)
```

Changing null to "True" notifies django that this field(genero) can be left null. Hence, no Integrity Error.

And don't forget migration.

Comment: I think you meant "don't forget migrations."